# Eigenvalues of a matrix, assuming symmetry

Tags: r, julia, linear-algebra

I am trying to find the eigenvalues of the following 2 X 2 matrix (equal to `a`) in Julia:

```
2×2 Array{Float64,2}:
0.120066  0.956959
0.408367  0.422321
```

I have the same array in R, and running the following R command I get this output:

```
eigen(a, symmetric=T, only.values=T)
$values
[1]  0.706626 -0.164245
```

In Julia, however, when I run this command I get this output:

```
eigvals(LowerTriangular(a))
2-element Array{Float64,1}:
0.120066
0.422321
```

Is there a way to replicate the R `eigen()` function for symmetric matrices in Julia because my way with the `LowerTriangular` function is not working?

Comment: Can you please clarify your intent for doing `eigen( ..., symmetric=TRUE )` on a non-symmetric matrix?

Comment: @ArtemSokolov I am working with a symmetric matrix

Comment: Question/comment: it seems odd that you're computing a symmetric eigenvalue on a matrix that seems obviously non-symmetric. `?eigen` clarifies that when using `symmetric=TRUE` "only [the matrix's] lower triangle (diagonal included) is used". So `Symmetric` will work as @BogumiłKamiński explains below, by simply enforcing symmetry by copying the lower triangle to the upper triangle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Symmetric` function like this:

```
julia> eigvals(Symmetric(x, :L))
2-element Array{Float64,1}:
 -0.164241
  0.706628
```

Since Julia 0.7 you will have to use `using LinearAlgebra` to import the functions.

Answer (score 3):

```
> x
         [,1]     [,2]
[1,] 0.120066 0.956959
[2,] 0.408367 0.422321
```

In Julia, `eigvals(LowerTriangular(a))` computes the eigen values of the lower triangular part of `x` (that is, the entries of the strict upper triangular part are set to 0):

```
> xx <- x
> xx[1,2] <- 0
> eigen(xx, only.values = TRUE)
$values
[1] 0.422321 0.120066 # same as Julia
```

While in R, `eigen(x, symmetric=TRUE)` assumes `x` is symmetric and takes the lower triangular part to derive the other entries:

```
> xx <- x
> xx[1,2] <- x[2,1]
> eigen(xx, only.values = TRUE)
$values
[1]  0.7066279 -0.1642409
> eigen(x, only.values = TRUE, symmetric = TRUE)
$values
[1]  0.7066279 -0.1642409
```

Comment: How could I get the values output from R to equal the values output from Julia with Julia code?

Comment: @L.Klum This is shown in my answer. Anyway, *the eigenvalues of a triangular matrix are the entries on its diagonal*. You don't need `eigen`...

Comment: Sorry-I don't think I was clear (my english is not very good). I need the 0.7066279 and -0.1642409 values from R to be created in Julia.